# Booting Solaris from Hard Disk or USB..?

Tags: boot, multi-boot, boot-camp, bootloader, solaris

Does anyone know how to boot Solaris 11 form an internal/external HDD? I have already done dual boot form CD ROM.  I just need to knoww how to boot from a USB Flash Drive and/or a HDD.

Comment: The Macintosh comes with a perfectly good UNIX operating system. Why replace it?

Comment: People usually suppose a dual boot on a CD ROM is harder to create than on your HDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the USB chipset(s) are supported by Solaris for boot....

To install a bootable copy on a USB drive, see the section titled "USB Install Images for x86" on this [page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/downloads/index.html).

To install a bootable copy on a HDD drive, follow the normal installation procedures.  To install on an external drive, have the drive attached during install and specify that drive as the installation destination.  Here is Oracle's [Installing Oracle Solaris 11 Systems documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E21798/index.html).

Dual booting would be done the same as with dual booting using the CD/DVD-ROM drive.